# Routing Error: No Route Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a routing error even though I believe the action exists in my controller.

**routes.rb:**

```
Build::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
     match 'users/:id' => 'users#username'
     get 'validate_username', on: :member
     get 'validate_email', on: :member
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb:**

```
 $("#user_email").on('blur', function(){
    if($(this).val()!=""){
        user_email = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<%=validate_email_user_path%>",
            type:'GET',
            data: {email: user_email},
            success: function(data,status,xhr){
                console.log(data);
                alert(data.message);
        });
```

**rake routes:**

```
  validate_email_user GET    /users/:id/validate_email(.:format)                         users#validate_email
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass in just the email and not an existing user, then I would think you need to update your routes.

This:

`get 'validate_email', on: :member`

Should be

`get 'validate_email/:email', on: :collection`

Within the users 'collection', you do not need to pass a user/user id into the _path helper. The actual URL for your route would be /users/validate_email instead of /users/:id/validate_email

The :email part of the route would make params[:email] available in your controller method.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting a strange error.  For some reason, it's passing the params id = validate_email.  Here is my log message: Started GET "/users/validate_email?email=test%40test.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-05 17:53:20 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"test@test.com", "id"=>"validate_email"}

Comment: What was the "final" route that you went with in the routes.rb file? Just so I answer/respond correctly :)

Comment: ok, it ended up working with this: get 'validate_email', on: :collection.  many thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool! I didn't realize you were passing the email as a URL var (a la users/validate_email?email=xxx). Glad it's working!

Answer (score 2):

You somehow have to pass in the :id

```
validate_email_user_path user.id
```

or

```
validate_email_user_path user
```

Comment: ok, but I'm validating the email address a user enters when they sign up, so I don't actually want to point to a particular user id (no one is signed in yet).  how would I do this?

Comment: I haven't implemented it by myself so far, but i would suggest to try something like get `'users/:email/validate_email' => 'users#show'` or check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Comment: right but the route you specified requires the id of the user.  the :id part is non negotiable. If you want to explicitly validate a users email before they register consider creating a route that accepts only user_email as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the URL helper with a user.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but maybe helpful.

Do you know the client_side_validations gem? I think you can use it, instead of implement everything by your own. It is available on github.